# Google Tracking between a domain and a subdomain on a different domain

Tags: google-analytics

If the title is not descriptive enough, here is what I'm trying to do.

I have four sites.
Let's say,

1. `example.com` and its store in `example.another-domain.com` and
2. `example2.com` and its store in `example2.another-domain.com`.

Is there any way to track visitors between each pair with google analytics?

As I have read [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite) there are some options, with the best fitting is the [one](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#domainAndSubDirectory) that tracks visits between a domain and a subdomain of another domain. But still it's not what I want exactly.

Any thoughts/pointers very welcome.

Cheers!

Comment: Actually this is what you want - it works the same way even when multiple domains are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Google Analytics creates a new visitor ID for each domain (or subdomain).  What you want to do is "tell" Google Analytics to keep the same visitor ID when a visitor goes from one domain to another, e.g. from example.com to example.another-domain.com

The "Multiple Domains and Sub-Domains" scenario is the one to follow.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains